# To which byte of `int` an `int *` points?

Tags: c, pointers

An `int *` points to the byte of the `int` which has the lowest memory address, not the byte that is the least significant. Is this correct? I always forget this and have to re-learn it. I searched the web for several minutes but wasn't able to find an answer (certainly my search wasn't long enough).

Comment: Yes. Why does this matter?

Comment: @tkausl, because we want to write codes which work correctly regardless of the endianness of the hardware.

Comment: To deal with endianness well it's best to stick to value operators, rather than pointer manipulation. E.g. to get the LSB of the int, use `i & 0x000000ff`, rather than calculate a pointer to the LSB. If you need to read/write data reliably from/to files/streams, use something like Google Protocol Buffers instead of writing data direct from memory. That'll sort out all and any endianness issues for you.

Comment: If it's an `int*` then you won't be reading one byte but the whole integer so it doesn't matter how it is stores, unless it's say, a file header that uses a different endianness. If you are dealing with hardware multibyte registers it may matter which sequence you read or write them, so you may want to read those bytes individually (with `uint8_t *`).

Comment: @i486, It wasn't in my question history here, and I didn't found a similar question by someone else. So I asked it. This is a Q&A website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An `int *` points to the byte of the `int` which has the lowest memory address, not the byte that is the least significant

Yes, I think this is a decent way of remembering it.

I would say it like this to make it more general: **a pointer to an object points to the beginning of the object in memory**.

Now, for `int` and similar integral types, the system's endiannes decides the order of the bytes in memory, so the beginning of an `int` may be the most significant byte (MSB) on *big-endian* systems, the least significant byte (LSB) on *little-endian* systems, or even something else.

Comment: And then you have the weirdness of so-called ["middle-endian" (or "mixed endian") systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian). That's entirely historical at this point, but it's a fun quirk that you had to consider if you were doing terrible stuff involving storing raw representations of your data to a file and expecting it to be read by other systems.

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point, I always forget crazy systems like that exist (or have existed) :')

Comment: You've forgotten the PDP-11, the progenitor of Unix? Shame on you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you print the contents of that pointer as raw binary, it will print the lowest address of the pointed-at `int`.

But strictly speaking an `int*` is a pointer with some type knowledge built-in. If you do something like `*ptr & 0xFF`, you will always mask out the lowest byte regardless of how the `int` is stored in memory. Meaning that most operators can be used portably on the de-referenced pointer without caring about where things are stored.

For example this code is portable between little and big endian:

```c
unsigned int i = 0x11223344;
unsigned int* ptr = &i;
printf("%X\n", *ptr & 0xFF);     // always 44
printf("%X\n", *ptr>>24 & 0xFF); // always 11
```

(using `unsigned` to avoid various problems with sign and bit-wise operators)

Whereas the code below is not portable, since it prints the raw binary in address order:

```c
unsigned char* cptr = (unsigned char*)&i;
printf("%X\n", *cptr);     // 44 or 11
printf("%X\n", cptr[3]);   // 44 or 11
```

We'd get 44 11 in case of little endian and 11 44 in case of big endian.